# No internet through router

Tags: cisco, routing, router, cisco-ios, internet

I have the following network setup, but on the computer I can't access anything that's outside of the TP-Link router. When I tried to ping 8.8.8.8, I got `reply from 192.168.2.1:Destination Host Unreachable`. I can access everything connected to the TP-Link router(192.168.0.*).

[image]
 .

Here's what I did with the Cisco router:

```
(config)int ge0/0
(config-if)ip add 192.168.0.200 255.255.255.0
(config-if)ip nat out
(config-if)no shut
(config)int ge0/1
(config-if)ip add 192.168.2.1 255.255.255.0
(config-if)ip nat in
(config-if)no shut
(config)access-list 100 permit ip 192.168.2.0 0.0.0.255 any
(config)ip nat inside source list 100 int ge0/0 overload
```

Comment: The address in your reply, `192.168.0.2.1` is an invalid IP address. You should always copy and paste messages to prevent typos. What does it actually say? Also, your TP-Link router is off-topic here. I really don't understand why you need it.

Comment: I say TP-Link router to avoid confusing it with the other router.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you do not seem to have a default route in your Cisco router, so the Cisco router has no idea where to send the traffic for any destinations that are not directly connected, and routers drop traffic for which they have no destination. A router that drops traffic should also send an ICMP message, such as the one that you received.

Routers learn routes in three ways:

1. Directly connected networks
2. Statically configured routes
3. Through dynamic routing protocols

Assuming your Internet router has a default route, you could run a common routing protocol between the two routers and advertise the default route to your Cisco router, or you can statically configure a default route in your Cisco router:

```
ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 GigabitEthernet0/0 192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

NAT overload configuration for translating  private ip address to public address seems to be partially correct .But while nat translation private should translate to public ip which is configured on interfàce G0/0 . So ensure interfàce G0/0 should configured with ISP provided public ip address ..

Further to reach traffic towards destination proper routing should be in place . In this case while  accessing internet traffic is destined to internet a default route pointing to ISP gateway should be configured in router ..